# How do we select tabs in the ssTabcontrol now?

Tags: vb6

Using VB6

sstab name as sstab1

Tab one was named "t1" and tab two was named "t2"

Code in vb.net

```
sstab1.selectedtab = t1 ' for tab one
sstab1.selectedtab = t2 ' for tab two
```

How to write a code in VB

Need VB6 Code Help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply;

```
sstab1.Tab = n
```

Where `n` is the 0 based index, so `sstab1.Tab = 0` for the 1st tab.